# RE in Python - lastindex attribute

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing tutorial about "advanced" regular expressions for Python,
and I cannot understand

```
lastindex
```

attribute. Why is it always 1 in the given examples:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastindex

I mean this example:

```
re.match('((ab))', 'ab').lastindex
```

Why is it 1? Second group is matching too.

Comment: No, it is 1 or 2 in the examples given.

Comment: this is computed during the matching process and is sort of a bi product, since the last closing group is the 1st, you're getting lastindex 1

Answer (score 3):

`lastindex` is the index of the last group that matched. The examples in the documentation include one that uses 2 capturing groups:

```
(a)(b)
```

where `lastindex` is set to 2 as the last capturing group to match was `(b)`.

The attribute comes in handy when you have optional capturing groups; compare:

```
>>> re.match('(required)( optional)?', 'required').lastindex
1
>>> re.match('(required)( optional)?', 'required optional').lastindex
2
```

When you have *nested* groups, the outer group is the last to match. So with `((ab))` or `((a)(b))` the outer group is group 1 and the last to match.

Comment: Your explanation is clear and intuitive. But I don't understand example from documentation which returns 1. I've just updated my question.

Comment: If I had "optional capturing groups" like you said, I would use MatchObject.group(number) and get None if not matched. lastindex attribute has to be for something else...

Comment: @TomekWyderka: sure, but you asked what `lastindex` means.

Answer (score 1):

In regex groups are captured using `()`. In python `re` the `lastindex` holds the last capturing group.

Lets see this small code example:

```
match = re.search("(\w+).+?(\d+).+?(\W+)", "input 123 ---")
if match:
    print match.lastindex
```

In this example, the output will be 3 as I have used three `()` in my regex and it matched all of those.

For the above code, if you execute the following line in `if` block, it will output `123` as it is the second capture group.

```
print match.group(2)
```

Comment: Please check out example I've added to my question.