# bencode including some binary data

Tags: python

I am using [bencode library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bencode/1.0.2) and I am trying to encode and decode binary data:

```
>>> import bencode
>>> bencode.Bencoder.decode(bencode.Bencoder.encode({'x': b'xyz'}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    bencode.Bencoder.decode(bencode.Bencoder.encode({'x': b'xyz'}))
  File "/home/pt12lol/virtualenv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 228, in decode
    return _decode(becode_string)
  File "/home/pt12lol/virtualenv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 197, in _decode
    data = _decode_item(pf, six.next(src))
  File "/home/pt12lol/virtualenv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 178, in _decode_item
    tok = next()
  File "/home/pt12lol/virtualenv-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 147, in _tokenizer
    s = m.group(m.lastindex)  # 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489243/re-in-python-lastindex-attribute
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How can I manage it?

Comment: The particular `bencode` implementation you're using is broken; it does not properly handle dictionaries containing more than one item, or containing a nested dictionary.  I couldn't reproduce the exact error you got, but the line numbers in your traceback don't match mine, so you apparently have a different version that's broken in different/additional ways.  The bencode implementation you get from `pip install bencode` seems to work just fine, although the interface is a bit different.

Comment: I tried that one, but it claimed on missing `BTL` module. Tbh I want to use it only in encoding/decoding purposes and having bit torrent libraries does not attract me.

Comment: If you don't need to interoperate with existing code, JSON has comparable encode/decode capabilities, and has been built-in since Python 2.6.

Comment: Yup, but I am looking for encoding a bit  more efficient with binary stuff.

Comment: Moreover, serializing the same dictionary with json ends up with `TypeError` saying that binary data is not JSON serializable.